# Send <esc>a with picocom

Tags: linux, serial-port

I have connect a USB serial adapter to my Linux box. I'm trying to connect to the device with picocom and I have to send an escape sequence like

```
<esc>-a
```

(hex: 1B 61)

How to do this,

```
<ctrl-a><esc>a ?
```

Comment: What happens when you press the `Esc` key followed by `a`?

Comment: It happens nothing and I'm not shure if I give wrong input or my device is not working as expected.

Comment: Have you configured the device and the USB serial adapter to both use the same speed, parity, number of data-bits and stop-bits? e.g. 9600-N-8-1